# What does it mean to wield a blank check?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

An enigmatic patron caught the wind off our rum business; he wields a blank check with our name on it.

Does this imply that the business itself is shady, and the person wielding the check is intrested in some sort of business dealing.

Comment: Do you mean _caught wind of_ (learned of its existence)?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

A blank cheque is literally a cheque that has been signed with no amount mentioned, implying that the person receiving the cheque can fill in any amount his heart desires.

Metaphorically, the phrase implies a state of absolute freedom to do as one pleases or an open offer that is hard to refuse,

Without adequate context, I can only imagine that the "patron" is interested in buying a stake in the operation at any cost